# Почему не работает обводка?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать без установки высоты блока?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZR7u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к блоку `.bubbles-block` свойство `overflow: hidden;` - из-за того, что внутри этого блока содержатся плавающие блоки c `float: right` и `float: left`, они выпадают из потока документа, и высота родительского блока равна нулю, соответственно граница обводится вокруг блока нулевой высоты.
http://jsfiddle.net/RZR7u/7/
Или воспользуйтесь способом очищения потока через псевдоэлемент `after`, описанным здесь [How to avoid empty clear divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874877/how-to-avoid-empty-clear-divs)